# Why can opening a Couchbase bucket be very slow?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, amazon-ec2, couchbase

I'm trying to use Couchbase from .NET with the official SDK. I'm hosting the Couchbase cluster in **Amazon EC2**.
The machine I'm trying to connect from is hosted in **Microsoft Azure**.

For some reason, opening a bucket is extremely slow, this afternoon it took ~3 seconds to open a bucket, but now for some reason it's more than 10 seconds.
The memory and CPU utilization of the Couchbase servers are very low.

My configuration:

```
<couchbaseClients>
  <couchbase useSsl="false" operationLifespan="1000">
    <servers>
      <!-- Ip addresses obscured... -->
      <add uri="http://1.1.1.1:8091/pools"></add>
      <add uri="http://1.1.1.2:8091/pools"></add>
    </servers>
  </couchbase>
</couchbaseClients>
```

The code I'm trying:

```
var cluster = new Cluster("couchbaseClients/couchbase");

using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("bucketname")) // This is taking 10-50 seconds.
{
    var obj = new TestClass { };

    // This is fast
    var result = bucket.Insert(new Document<TestClass> { Content = obj, Expiry = 300000, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
}

using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("bucketname")) // This is taking 10-50 seconds.
{
    var obj = new TestClass { };

    // This is fast
    var result = bucket.Insert(new Document<TestClass> { Content = obj, Expiry = 300000, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
}

using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("bucketname")) // This is taking 10-50 seconds.
{
    var obj = new TestClass { };

    // This is fast
    var result = bucket.Insert(new Document<TestClass> { Content = obj, Expiry = 300000, Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
}
```

I tried to optimize by using `ClusterHelper.GetBucket()` instead of `cluster.OpenBucket()`, but the first `GetBucket()` is still very slow (everything else is fast in that case).

I experimented with other calls on the bucket (Get, Contains, etc.), and everything is fast, only opening the bucket itself is slow.

How can I troubleshoot what the problem is?

**UPDATE**: I set up logging based on @jeffrymorris' suggestion, and the I see the following error messages at the point where we spend a lot of time:

```
DEBUG Couchbase.Configuration.Server.Providers.ConfigProviderBase - Bootstrapping with 127.0.0.1:11210
INFO Couchbase.IO.ConnectionPool... Node 127.0.0.1:11210 failed to initialize, reason: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time...
```

And after this there are three other exceptions about trying to connect to `127.0.0.1:11210`, and there are seconds passed between those messages, so this is causing the slowness.
Why is the client trying to connect to localhost? I don't have that anywhere in my configuration.

I debugged the code of couchbase-net-client, and this is happening when I call `OpenBucket()` in `CarrierPublicationProvider.GetConfig()`. It gets the bucket configuration object, and for some reason it contains not one of the servers I configured in the web.config, but `localhost:8091` instead. I'm still trying to figure out why this is happening.

(This is probably not happening on my dev machine, because there I have a local Couchbase server installation. If I stop that, then it gets slow there as well, and I'm seeing the same `Bootstrapping with 127.0.0.1:11210` error messages in the logs.)

Comment: What size EC2 instance are you running this on? Are you running your code on the same instance as Couchbase or on a separate instance?

Comment: @BruceP since then I started debugging the code of couchbase-net-client, and the 10 seconds delay is happening because the method `HttpStreamingProvider.RegisterObserver` is doing a `Wait()` on an event with a 10 second timeout. So I don't think this is related to the server performance. I'm still debugging to figure out why this is happening.
No, I'm running the client code on my own machine.

Comment: What's the network latency between the two?

I'd be interested to know if you have an instance in AWS using the same code whether it'd have the same problems.

Comment: Are you opening a Couchbase (persistent) or Memcached (in-memory) bucket? The reason I ask is that the HttpStreamingProvider is only used by CB buckets if the initial CCCP bootstrapping failed, which could explain the lag; memcached always uses HttpStreaming. You can try enabling logging as well to see what is happening during the bootstrapping process: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/dotnet-2.2/setting-up-logging.html

Comment: @Kirk: I don't know the latency, but that shouldn't be the problem, since the actual Insert or Read is fast. I'll test from another environment as well.

Comment: @jeffrymorris: Yep, it's a Couchbase bucket. Good idea, I didn't know about logging, I'll try that.

Comment: @jeffrymorris I found something fishy in the logs, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figuring out the problem took some debugging of the Couchbase client code, and looking at the logs (thanks for the tip, @jeffrymorris!).

It turns out that if you don't have any preconfigured bucket, then the client will initially try to connect to localhost:8091 (event if that's not in your `servers` section), which can take seconds until it realizes there is no server there. This doesn't happen if you have *any* bucket configured.

So I had to change my configuration from this:

```
<couchbaseClients>
  <couchbase useSsl="false" operationLifespan="1000">
    <servers>
      <!-- Ip addresses obscured... -->
      <add uri="http://1.1.1.1:8091/pools"></add>
      <add uri="http://1.1.1.2:8091/pools"></add>
    </servers>
  </couchbase>
</couchbaseClients>
```

To this:

```
<couchbaseClients>
  <couchbase useSsl="false" operationLifespan="1000">
    <servers>
      <!-- Ip addresses obscured... -->
      <add uri="http://1.1.1.1:8091/pools"></add>
      <add uri="http://1.1.1.2:8091/pools"></add>
    </servers>
    <buckets>
      <add name="default" useSsl="false" operationLifespan="1000">
      </add>
    </buckets>
  </couchbase>
</couchbaseClients>
```

Note that I'm not actually going to use a bucket called `default`, but having the configuration there sill prevent the client from trying to connect to localhost. (This is happening in the method `ConfigProviderBase.GetOrCreateConfiguration`.)

**Update**: The issue has been fixed here: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/commit/020093b422a78728dd49d75d9fe9f1e00d01a0f2

Comment: Turns out the performance from Azure to Amazon is still terrible, but for another reason, I posted a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204339/use-couchbase-hosted-in-amazon-from-a-client-hosted-in-azure-what-can-cause-bad

Comment: What sort of speed did you get it down to with this? I found the Couchbase .net client averaged about 10x longer than the equivalent call via Enyim client (calling a memcached bucket) - over 100ms vs 10ms for Enyim. Out of interest, did you set up your bucket with a standard or dedicated port?

Comment: 100ms sounds wrong. I did some measurements (documented here: http://blog.markvincze.com/simple-client-side-compression-for-couchbase-with-benchmarks/), and I got numbers in the range of 10-20 ms, depending on the data and the serializer.

Comment: You were right - I looked at your blog which was really helpful. Using the ClusterHelper got the times down to the level I would expect. Many thanks.